# POST-Request with JSON Data over HTTPS Connection with Qt5

Tags: json, post, request, qt5

I'm trying to send a POST request over an HTTPS-Connection via Qt5 to a Web-API, but I keep getting the following error-message:

> Failure "Error downloading https://.../login - server replied: BAD REQUEST"
>
> Reply:`"{"error_tag": "ARGUMENT_MISSING", "error_code": 19, "error_extra": {"argument": "email"}, "error": "Required argument is missing"}"`

It seems like the HTTPS Connection works, but the POST request is faulty...

```
    void connection::sendLoginData(){
        QUrl url = QString("https://.../login");
        QNetworkRequest req(url);
//Creating the JSON-Data
        QJsonDocument json;
        QJsonObject data;

        data["email"] = QString("a@g.com");
        data["password"] = QString("---");

        json.setObject(data);
        QByteArray jsonPost = QJsonDocument(data).toJson();

        req.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader,QVariant("application/json; charset=utf-8"));
        req.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentLengthHeader, QByteArray::number(jsonPost.size()));

//Sending the Request
        QNetworkReply *reply = manager->post(req,jsonPost);

    // Connection via HTTPS
        QFile certFile(SSLCERTIFICATE);
        certFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
        QSslCertificate cert(&certFile, QSsl::Pem);
        QSslSocket * sslSocket = new QSslSocket(this);
        sslSocket->addCaCertificate(cert);
        QSslConfiguration configuration = sslSocket->sslConfiguration();
        configuration.setProtocol(QSsl::TlsV1_2);

        sslSocket->setSslConfiguration(configuration);
        reply->setSslConfiguration(configuration);

    }
```

this is the Slot which is called when QNetworkReply gets a reply:

```
void connection::onFinished(QNetworkReply *reply){
    if (reply->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError) {
        //success
        qDebug() << "Success" <<reply->readAll();
        delete reply;
    }
    else {
        //failure
        qDebug() << "Failure" <<reply->errorString();
        qDebug() << "Reply: " << reply->readAll();
        delete reply;
    }
}
```

The Signal "finished" of QNetworkReply is of course connected to the "onFinished"-Slot

```
    MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    manager = new QNetworkAccessManager;
    ui->setupUi(this);
    Connector = new connection(ui,manager);
connect(manager,SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),Connector,SLOT(onFinished(QNetworkReply*)));

}
```

Maybe someone of you could tell me what's wrong with the POST-Request? Looking at the Reply of the Server it seems like the JSON-Data is never sent, or somehow formatted in a wrong way...

Comment: The data is definitely sent to your server. If  not it would not answer. BAD REQUEST means you have syntax error in your Json. What kind of syntax error? Impossible to say... your server, your application. Might be as easy as that your server does not understand the official **"application/json;..**, but expects something like "text/json" or  "text/javascript". Btw... the **QJsonDocument json;** in your code... did you intend to use it somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you didn't provide the exact URL, I'd suggest you to try to check `url.isValid()` and url.`errorString()`.

I just had an issue, the code worked fine in Qt 4.8, but in Qt 5.4 all my POST requests got 400 Bad Request reply. 
I looked into the TCP dump via Wireshark and found out that the URL was wrong. 
In my case `url.setPath("api/register");` was the line that caused the problem. It should have been `url.setPath("/api/register");`

Hope it helps.